# `require` vs. `gem` methods?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

What's the difference between the `require` and `gem` methods?

For example, what's the difference between`require 'minitest'` and `gem 'minitest'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you have two versions of the gem `foo` installed:

```
$ gem list foo

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

foo (2.0.1, 2.0.0)
```

---

If you use only `require`, the newest version will be loaded by default:

```
require 'foo'       # => true

Foo::VERSION        # => "2.0.1"
```

---

If you use `gem` before calling `require`, you can specify a different version to use:

```
gem 'foo', '2.0.0'  # => true
require 'foo'       # => true

Foo::VERSION        # => "2.0.0"
```

---

**Note**: using `gem` without subsequently calling `require` does not load the gem.

```
gem 'foo'           # => true

Foo::VERSION        # => NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
```

Answer (score 6):

[Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/current/Kernel.html#method-i-require) activates the latest version of a gem.

[Kernel#gem](https://ruby-doc.org/current/stdlibs/rubygems/Kernel.html#method-i-gem) (added by [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/)) allows activation of specific [gem versions](https://ruby-doc.org/current/stdlibs/rubygems/Gem/Version.html); for example, `gem 'stack', '>= 1.2'`.

Comment: It seems from the answer that `gem` is a replacement for `require`, actually `gem` just tells `require` which version of a gem to load.

Comment: *Kernel#gem* only **activates** a specific version of the specified gem. You must then *Kernel#require* the gem to load it; therefore, you must call `gem` before `require`.